# Whether a bread crumb can be added in Developer edition

Tags: visualforce, detail

Most of you could have seen links similar to `« Back to List: Custom Object Definitions` in many of the standard pages . The user permission needed to add this link were listed as

```
Site.com Publisher User field enabled on the user detail page
AND
Site administrator or designer role assigned at the site level
```

even after assigning the role , i cant see any option to add the link . Is this available in Developer edition , if so how can i add it to my pages.

Comment: So, are you asking about Site.com or Visualforce?  Your question is tagged as visualforce which isn't part of Site.com and it references standard object pages which also aren't part of Site.com, but your question references a Site.com help page.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation quoted is irrelevant to the question at hand. The `« Back to List: Custom Object Definitions` link is automatically provided on standard pages, and is determined by the last view you were looking at. As far as I am aware, Visualforce doesn't have a way to access what the "last list" was, so you cannot include this link in Visualforce pages (corrections welcome). You should note that this is a *list*, meaning that you have to view a list before this breadcrumb will appear. For example, if you click on the Contacts tab, then click "Go!" next to the "View" dropdown, then click on any record, the link changes to `« Back to List: Contacts`. If you do not view a list, you will not see this link. It is available in *all* editions, including Contact Edition, Group Edition, Professional Edition, Performance Edition, Unlimited Edition, and Developer Edition.

Comment: so there is no way to add this in any of the custom pages

Comment: There's no API to get the breadcrumb, and as far as I'm aware, it's not automatically added to a Visualforce page, so there isn't any convenient means of providing this link.

Comment: The language you cite seems to come from [this help page](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_breadcrumb_add.htm&language=en_US), and is about the Site.com CMS/visual web site builder, not Visualforce coded pages, which is what @sfdcfox is answering about. 

On that page, it details how to drag a "Breadcrumb" element onto a page or page template. It also notes at the top that the feature is limited in Developer Edition. I've not spent any time with Site.com in Dev or Prod orgs, just trying to help get folks on the same page.

Comment: Breadcrumbs can be added to Site.com pages in Developer Editions.  I believe that all Site.com help pages have the "available with limitations" on them.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use the browser History and some Javascript inserted at the top of the VF page to insert a link, e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.getElementsByClassName("ptBreadcrumb")[0].innerHTML='&nbsp;«&nbsp;<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Back</a>';
</script>
```

Any comments?